# Proxy para acessar Webservice

Tags: php

Eu alimento um banco de dados com pegando dados de um webservice

```
function pegarWS($produto){

$PRODUTO_WS = 'http://webservice.com/s/produto/';
$URL = $PRODUTO_WS.$produto;
```

Ele acessa a URL http://webservice.com/s/produto/ com o nome do produto ($produto) no final.

Esse webservice é grátis e tem um limites de requisição.

Eu gostaria de passar por um proxy (proxy.txt) com ips de proxy.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a API do http://gimmeproxy.com/. Ela tem a versão gratuita e a versão.

A forma de capturar para ambas versões, é a mesma coisa e só muda um parâmetro na URL.

Para capturar um proxy, basta fazer uma requisição para `https://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy` com alguns dos parâmetros abaixo:

- `api_key=<your-key>`: Sua key (caso seja a versão paga)
- `get=true`: Para proxy com suporte a requisições GET
- `post=true`: Para proxy com suporte a requisições POST
- `supportsHttps=true`: Para proxy com suporte a HTTPS
- `country:BR,US`: Para proxy de determinados países. Separar por vírgula
- `minSpeed`: Velocidade mínima em Kbps do proxy

<sup>Para mais parâmetros, acesse o site acima.</sup>

Para fazer a captura no PHP, basta utilizar a biblioteca `cURL` ou `file_get_contetns`.

Exemplo:

```
$proxy = json_decode( file_get_contents("https://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy") );
var_dump( $proxy );
```

Com parâmetros

```
$proxy = json_decode( file_get_contents("https://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?supportsHttp=true&get=true") );
var_dump( $proxy );
```

Para salvar esses proxy em um arquivo `txt`, basta utilizar `file_put_contents`:

```
$proxy = file_get_contents("https://gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?supportsHttp=true&get=true");

file_put_contents( "ips.txt", print_r($proxy, true), FILE_APPEND )
                   └───┬───┘  └─────────┬──────────┘ └─────┬─────┘
                       │                │                  └──────── Utilize esse parâmetro para não sobrescrever o arquivo.
                       │                └─────────────────────────── Conteúdo do arquivo
                       └──────────────────────────────────────────── Nome do arquivo
```